# How do I set the Django auth.login session length/age?

Tags: django, django-authentication

I have a Django app deployed on Google App Engine that prematurely logs its users out. But no browser window/ tab is closed. In settings.py, I have this code:

```
SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = False
```

I also tried using this code right after calling `auth.login()`:

```
request.session.set_expiry(30*24*60*60)
```

Is there any way that I can let the length of the auth.login session be much longer, say, a year?

Comment: Do you have more information about what is happening when the user is getting logged out?

Comment: What session back-end are you using?

Comment: Please check in the browser if the cookie has expire time in the future. And if is't being deleted after browser restart.

Comment: User is logged out when request.user.is_authenticated() (which is what I use to authenticate users) returns false. Cookies expire 1 month later, as seen in Safari. Cookies stay there when browser restarts. My session engine is: django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache, as set in settings.py. Should I use another back-end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using cache-based session back-end it is possible that the session data get's removed from the cache, which for user will look like he/she has been logged out. Memcache can/will delete data in some cases, i.e to make room for your new data.

To narrow down the problem i recommend:

- checking if the session actually gets removed from cache
- switching to different session back-end, to see if the problem will disappear.

Comment: I switched to django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache_db for my sessions back-end, and so far the session has been persistent (24 hours so far).